# detect unchecked division operator

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Basically I am writing a clang-tidy check to detect "bad" divisions where there is a division and the divisor was not checked with an `assert()` statement.

In the following example `good_disvisor` should pass the check as there is an `assert` checking it's equality to zero but `bad_divisor` should be detected and marked.

```cpp
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    const double good_divisor = 0.3;
    assert(good_divisor != 0.0);
    double foo = 1.0 / good_divisor;

    const double bad_divisor = 0.3;
    double bar = 1.0 / bad_divisor;

    return 0;
}
```

So far my machers and check can only detect the divison opeartor but couldn't do much beyond it:

```cpp
void UnsafeArithmeticCheck::registerMatchers(MatchFinder *Finder) {
  Finder->addMatcher(binaryOperator(hasOperatorName("/")).bind("div"), this);
}

void UnsafeArithmeticCheck::check(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
  const auto *Binop = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<BinaryOperator>("div");

  if (!Binop) {
    return;
  }

  diag(Binop->getExprLoc(), "found a division here", DiagnosticIDs::Note);

  auto rhs = Binop->getRHS();
  // now how do I check if this `rhs` is a variable and not an expression?
}
```

I think there are 3 steps missing still:

1. to check if `rhs` from division operator is a variable (and not an expression). In my check I get it through `Binop->getRHS()` but I can't find an function to examine it's type
2. to check if there is an `asssert()` prior to the `DeclStmt` (the father node of this divison operator)
3. if there is such an `assert()`, then further check if there is a `rhs != 0` in it (`rhs` was identified from step 1)

Can someone help me to complete this check?

---

Answering @Scott's question (what I hope to achieve that `core.DivideZero` can't not):

`core.DivideZero` simply couldn't detect code like below:

```cpp
double foo(double x) {
    return x * 3 - 1;
}

int main() {
    double divisor = foo(0.3);
    double x = 1.0 / divisor;

    return 0;
}
```

And I hope my check can mark an error for:

```cpp
    double divisor = foo(0.3);
    double x = 1.0 / divisor;
```

and wouldn't raise an error when `assert()` added:

```cpp
    double divisor = foo(0.3);
    assert(divisor != 0);
    double x = 1.0 / divisor;
```

Comment: `clang-tidy` has `core.DivideZero`, implemented in [`DivZeroChecker.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/DivZeroChecker.cpp).  Perhaps looking at that code answers your questions?  Or if not, you could explain what you want to do that `core.DivideZero` does not.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak Thanks for your reply. I have added an another example in the question.

Comment: Although I still don't fully understand what it is doing, it looks to me as though `DivideZero` is simply choosing not to report when the divisor is unknown in order to limit the noise, but that it does possess the required value tracking to do so if it wanted.  Also look at the [test](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/test/Analysis/division-by-zero-track-zero.cpp).  Are you sure the existing checker can't be adjusted to behave the way you want?  (I'm just trying to understand the question, not dispute your intentions or methods.)

Comment: @ScottMcPeak "`DivideZero` is simply choosing not to report when the divisor is unknown". This is exactly what it can't do for me: I hope to report such case when the divisor is unkown *and without an `assert()` checking*.

Comment: From what I can tell, `clang-tidy` checks do not have easy access to the APIs needed to do a flow-sensitive analysis.  The `DivideZero` check is implemented as part of "Clang Static Analysis" (CSA), which is built in to `clang`, and `clang-tidy` merely exposes it as a convenience.  So: are you looking for a solution that works using the `clang-tidy` API only (and hence can be a stand-alone check program), or is something that uses CSA (and hence must be integrated into `clang`) acceptable?

Comment: @ScottMcPeak I don't think I have all the knowledge needed to understand what you explain. So allow me to clarify a bit in a layman way: regarding "flow-sensitive analysis", did you mean that "as a clang-tidy user you can detect either assert statement `assert(divisor != 0);` or `DeclStmt` `double x = 1.0 / divisor;` but there is noway to tell if one statement is before or after or next to the other?" Do I understand it correctly? To answer your last question, for this problem clang-tidy API is the only solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Right, "flow sensitive" means it tracks the order in which things appear.  See also [wikipedia: Data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis#Sensitivities).  I think the only flow-sensitive check written using the `clang-tidy` API is [`UseAfterMoveCheck.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/bugprone/UseAfterMoveCheck.cpp) and it works by building a CFG and traversing it with custom logic.